# Writing a macro or function to simplify global.R code in R Shiny app

Tags: r

So I currently have a working piece of code that imports some yearly data as csv files and merges on this data to a common shapefile to use later on while creating a map. While the code I have works, I would like to simplify it if possible. The code that I currently have in the `global.R` file is:

```
# importing the inputs
countymerge2004 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2004.csv") #county level yearly data
countymerge2005 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2005.csv")
countymerge2006 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2006.csv")
countymerge2007 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2007.csv")
countymerge2008 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2008.csv")
countymerge2009 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2009.csv")
countymerge2010 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2010.csv")
countymerge2011 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2011.csv")
countymerge2012 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2012.csv")
countymerge2013 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2013.csv")
countymerge2014 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2014.csv")
countymerge2015 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2015.csv")
countymerge2016 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2016.csv")
countymerge2017 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2017.csv")
countymerge2018 <- read.csv("Maps county level input data 2018.csv")
countymerge <- read.csv("Maps county level input data.csv") #county level data for all years
countybor <- readOGR("gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json", "OGRGeoJSON") #county borders as geoJSON

# cleaning the relevant variables (adding leading zeros)
countymerge2004$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2004$STATE)
countymerge2004$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2004$COUNTY)
countymerge2005$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2005$STATE)
countymerge2005$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2005$COUNTY)
countymerge2006$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2006$STATE)
countymerge2006$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2006$COUNTY)
countymerge2007$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2007$STATE)
countymerge2007$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2007$COUNTY)
countymerge2008$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2008$STATE)
countymerge2008$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2008$COUNTY)
countymerge2009$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2009$STATE)
countymerge2009$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2009$COUNTY)
countymerge2010$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2010$STATE)
countymerge2010$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2010$COUNTY)
countymerge2011$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2011$STATE)
countymerge2011$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2011$COUNTY)
countymerge2012$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2012$STATE)
countymerge2012$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2012$COUNTY)
countymerge2013$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2013$STATE)
countymerge2013$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2013$COUNTY)
countymerge2014$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2014$STATE)
countymerge2014$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2014$COUNTY)
countymerge2015$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2015$STATE)
countymerge2015$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2015$COUNTY)
countymerge2016$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2016$STATE)
countymerge2016$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2016$COUNTY)
countymerge2017$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2017$STATE)
countymerge2017$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2017$COUNTY)
countymerge2018$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge2018$STATE)
countymerge2018$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge2018$COUNTY)
countymerge$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",countymerge$STATE)
countymerge$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",countymerge$COUNTY)

# merge on county statistics to shapefile
countyborder2004 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2004, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2004)))
countyborder2005 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2005, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2005)))
countyborder2006 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2006, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2006)))
countyborder2007 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2007, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2007)))
countyborder2008 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2008, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2008)))
countyborder2009 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2009, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2009)))
countyborder2010 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2010, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2010)))
countyborder2011 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2011, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2011)))
countyborder2012 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2012, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2012)))
countyborder2013 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2013, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2013)))
countyborder2014 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2014, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2014)))
countyborder2015 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2015, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2015)))
countyborder2016 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2016, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2016)))
countyborder2017 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2017, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2017)))
countyborder2018 <- merge(countybor,countymerge2018, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge2018)))
countyborder_all <- merge(countybor,countymerge, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(countymerge)))
```

I have tried writing a function to simplify the whole cleaning and merging process but I cannot seem to get it to work for some reason.

```
yearlyClean <- function(indata, outdata){
  indata$STATE <- sprintf("%02d",indata$STATE)
  indata$COUNTY <- sprintf("%03d",indata$COUNTY)
  outdata <<- merge(countybor,indata, by = intersect(names(countybor),names(indata)))
}

yearlyClean(indata = countymerge2004, outdata = countyborder2004)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I normally code in SAS where I could use a macro and a do loop to automate most of this process but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax for R.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! How is this problem related to `shiny`?

Comment: You can't do assignment in this way, either use `assign` within the function rather than `<<-` or `return` the result of  your `merge` and assign when calling the funciton

Comment: It would help if you can also expand on "can't seem to get it to work for some reason" by including error codes when you run your function.

Comment: Ah it doesn't return an error. It just doesn't do what I want it to do. Right now, if I run the cleaning function, it just returns a dataset called `outdata` instead of the name I seem to be assigning it in the function call `outdata = countyborder2004`

Comment: @Chris how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @PoGibas it's technically an R problem, but its part of an R Shiny app